# Ruby: Get all keys in a hash (including sub keys)

Tags: ruby, hash

let's have this hash:

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => 3}}
hash.get_all_keys 
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

how can i get all keys since `hash.keys` returns just `["a", "b"]`

Comment: Thanks, but in future consider holding off a bit before selecting an answer, as it may discourage other, possibly better ones being offered.

Comment: can anybody suggest me on this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118179/logstash-ruby-segregate-key-values-from-nested-json

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will give you an array of all the keys for any level of nesting.

```
def get_em(h)
  h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),keys|      
    keys << k
    keys.concat(get_em(v)) if v.is_a? Hash
  end
end

hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => {"d" => 3}}}
get_em(hash) #  => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 9):

I find `grep` useful here:

```
def get_keys(hash)
  ( hash.keys + hash.values.grep(Hash){|sub_hash| get_keys(sub_hash) } ).flatten
end

p get_keys my_nested_hash #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I like the solution as it is short, yet it reads very nicely.

Answer (score 5):

#### Version that keeps the hierarchy of the keys

- Works with arrays
- Works with nested hashes

`keys_only.rb`

```
# one-liner
def keys_only(h); h.map { |k, v| v = v.first if v.is_a?(Array); v.is_a?(Hash) ? [k, keys_only(v)] : k }; end

# nicer
def keys_only(h)
  h.map do |k, v|
    v = v.first if v.is_a?(Array);

    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      [k, keys_only(v)]
    else
      k
    end
  end
end

hash = { a: 1, b: { c: { d: 3 } }, e: [{ f: 3 }, { f: 5 }] }
keys_only(hash)
# => [:a, [:b, [[:c, [:d]]]], [:e, [:f]]]
```

P.S.: Yes, it looks like a lexer :D

#### Bonus: Print the keys in a nice nested list

```
# one-liner
def print_keys(a, n = 0); a.each { |el| el.is_a?(Array) ? el[1] && el[1].class == Array ? print_keys(el, n) : print_keys(el, n + 1) : (puts "  " * n + "- #{el}") }; nil; end

# nicer
def print_keys(a, n = 0)
  a.each do |el|
    if el.is_a?(Array)
       if el[1] && el[1].class == Array
         print_keys(el, n)
       else
         print_keys(el, n + 1)
       end
    else
      puts "  " * n + "- #{el}"
    end
  end

  nil
end


> print_keys(keys_only(hash))
- a
  - b
      - c
        - d
  - e
    - f
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_all_keys(hash)
  hash.map do |k, v|
    Hash === v ? [k, get_all_keys(v)] : [k]
  end.flatten
end
```

Comment: === is asymmetric， that means v === Hash gives different result from Hash === v.

Comment: I think === is hard to read and understand, it should really only be used in case statements.

Comment: True, but that is, just like the case statement, a function build for the case equality operator.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look of following code for only one nested level:

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => 3}}
keys = hash.keys + hash.select{|_,value|value.is_a?(Hash)}
       .map{|_,value| value.keys}.flatten
p keys
```

result:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

---

**Update**: New recursive solution, considering multi-level nested input (as in [@Bala's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514438/bala) comments, e.g.: `hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => {"c" => 3}}, "c" => {"b" => 3}}`).

```
class Hash
  def recursive_keys
    if any?{|_,value| value.is_a?(Hash)}
       keys + select{|_,value|value.is_a?(Hash)}
                    .map{|_,value| value.recursive_keys}.flatten
    else
       keys
    end
  end
end

hash =  {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => {"d" => 3}}, "e" => {"f" => 3}}
p hash.recursive_keys
```

result:

```
["a", "b", "e", "c", "d", "f"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also deal with nested arrays that include hashes

```
def all_keys(items)
  case items
  when Hash then items.keys + items.values.flat_map { |v| all_keys(v) }
  when Array then items.flat_map { |i| all_keys(i) }
  else []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Hash

  def get_all_keys
    [].tap do |result|
      result << keys
      values.select { |v| v.respond_to?(:get_all_keys) }.each do |value| 
        result << value.get_all_keys
      end
    end.flatten
  end

end

hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => 3}}
puts hash.get_all_keys.inspect # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Interesting use of `tap`. You might want to use `__method__` in place of `:get_all_keys`.  If the method were renamed and that not changed, it might take awhile to find the bug. Aside: do you know why `respond to?` does not check to see if its argument is an existing method?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thank you, I like the idea with `__method__`. I do not understand your question about the behavior of `respond_to?`, please explain. It seams like I missed something important.

Comment: `v.respond_to?(sym)` => false for any Symbol `sym` that is not a method.  Ruby could check at runtime to see if `sym` is a method and raise an exception if not, but it evidently does not do so. I was wondering why.  It just occurred to me that for `method_missing` to be useful, Ruby probably never checks to see if a Symbol is an existing method.

Comment: Ruby seams to check only if the method name is in the `methods` array and therefore will not recognize if `method_missing` might respond. And to analyze all possible behavior of a `method_missing` is almost impossible without actually running that method, what might have side effects. Interesting read about the new `respond_to_missing?` in Ruby 1.9.2: http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/15/methodmissing-politely/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach :

```
def get_all_keys(h)
  h.each_with_object([]){|(k,v),a| v.is_a?(Hash) ? a.push(k,*get_all_keys(v)) : a << k }
end

hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => {"d" => 3}}}
p get_all_keys(hash)
# >> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Arup, I think `each_with_object` is greatly underused. Here, for example, one would often see `reduce([])` (aka `inject`) instead, but that requires the array holding the keys to be returned to the block, which may require that ugly `; keys`) at the end. I considered `each_with_object` here but decided to instead have `keys = []` before and `keys` after. One is often faced with this choice. I think the simpler way is more readable, but it does add two lines. Do you have an opinion about this?

Comment: @CarySwoveland In this kind of situation, I always used `each_with_object`. For me it looks more expressive in Ruby way. As I often found Ruby experts like short and concise, but expressive code. I tired to do the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this option works:

```
blah = {"a" => 1, "b" => {"c" => 3}}
results = []
blah.each do |k,v|
  if v.is_a? Hash
    results << k
    v.each_key {|key| results << key}
  else
    results << k
  end
end
puts results
```

Answer (score -1):

`hash.keys` is the simplest one I have seen to return an array of the key values in a hash.

Comment: But it doesn't return nested keys `{ a: { b: 1 } }.keys # [:a]` :(.